# string.format if else statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, format

How would I do if statement in string.format?
I need to check if x=0, x=1 or x=null
I know I can do with two values but I am not sure how to add another else statment here

```
String.Format("{0}", x == 0 ? "True" : "False")
```

Comment: What's the type of `x`? (If it's an `int`, it can't be null...)

Comment: And why are you using `string.Format` when the result is *just* the `True` or `False` string? You really need a more complete example before we can help you much...

Comment: hey Jon... I am rendering my title on my grid column. Therefore I need to format the title with my json data

Comment: That doesn't explain why you'd use `string.Format` with *just* a format string of `{0}`. Nor does it tell us the type of `x`. Again, a better example is required.

Comment: guys... all I wanted to know was how to add another else statement in the string.format? Thanks to Alex. Now I have already got it working... Thanks for your concern though Jon :)

Comment: Well you haven't even got a *single* "if/else" statement at the moment. If you don't care about making your code as readable as possible, go ahead and use multiple conditional operators in a single argument. If you *do*, you should *at least* pull the evaluation outside the method call... and possibly look at a different approach. Of course, that approach would depend on knowing the type of `x`, which you still haven't told us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0}", x == null ? "<null>": (x == 0 ? "True" : "False"))
```

Comment: Thanks Alex... this is all I needed to know(format) without all the extras... thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

> how to add another else statment here

Nesting of `?:` is possible but almost always a bad idea.

A direct answer, assuming `x` is `int?` is to just use `( )` :

```
 String.Format("{0}", x == null ? "Null" : (x.Value == 0 ? "True" : "False"))
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *always* a bad idea. I've seen it put to very good effect - but I wouldn't do it *within* the method call here...

Comment: I already put 'almost' in front of that. My alternative isn't that great either, but that's also from the confusion about the type of x.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like nesting of ternary ifs. In general case and depending on version of C# you use, you can try this:

```
var values = new Dictionary<int?, string>()
{
    { 0, "zero"},
    { 1, "one"},
    { 2, "two"},
    { null, "none"}
};

String.Format("{0}", values[x]);
```

IMO, tables always beat complex if statements for more than 3 values.

Comment: with more then 2-3 values it is far more readable then ternary if. Try adding another case to ternary if and see what's cleaner. Actually, don't add another, just express these 4 cases with it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer as well Zdeslav, but for my simple purpose, I am accepting Alex's answer